# Create new column, set value equal to static value in separate list in R

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
id    country   name    
1     BE        John
2     NL        Nancy
3     UK        Drew
4     UK        Ted
```

I want to add a new column, called population, which for each row will set its value equal to a statically assigned value. So I was thinking about using a static list like so:

`pop <- list(BE = 1500000, NL = 25000000, UK = 80000000)`

I have a lot of countries and would prefer to do this without a bunch of conditional statements. Basically I want to grab the key from the country column, look up the value in the pop list and put that value in the new population column.

Output should look like:

```
id    country   name    population
1     BE        John    15000000
2     NL        Nancy   25000000
3     UK        Drew    80000000
4     UK        Ted     80000000
```

Comment: Look at `?merge` or `?join` from `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert your `pop` into data frame and then create a new column in your data to get the value in `pop` where the value of country in data equal to the country in `pop`

```
data <- NULL
data$id = c(1,2,3,4)
data$country = c("BE","NL","UK","UK")
data$name = c("John","Nancy","Drew","Ted")
data <- data.frame(data)

pop <- list(BE = 1500000, NL = 25000000, UK = 80000000)
pop <- data.frame(pop)

data$population <- t(pop[data$country])
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options here.

- `dplyr::case_when` is useful if you have a low number of countries (like in your example). It is a vectorised wrapper to multiple `if else` statements.
- `dplyr::*_join` function family is the standard approach to this kind of problem if you have another table/dataframe that relates an ID to a value (e.g. country-population). In this case, `dplyr::left_join` solves it. (Perhaps you are not familiar with SQL?)

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(country = c("BE", "NL", "UK", "UK"),
             name = c("John", "Nancy", "Drew", "Ted"))

# Using `dplyr::case_when`
df %>%
  mutate(population = case_when(country == "BE" ~ 1500000L,
                                country == "NL" ~ 25000000L,
                                country == "UK" ~ 80000000L,
                                TRUE ~ NA_integer_))

# Using `dplyr::left_join` with a relational country-population dataframe
country_population <- tibble(country = c("BE", "NL", "UK"),
                             population = c(1500000L, 25000000L, 80000000L))

left_join(df, country_population, by = "country")


# A tibble: 4 x 3
  country name  population
  <chr>   <chr>      <int>
1 BE      John     1500000
2 NL      Nancy   25000000
3 UK      Drew    80000000
4 UK      Ted     80000000
```

Comment: Other functions from dplyr::xxx_join family are also worth noting - in this kind of context inner and right, at different times anti. But that is nitpicking... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `dplyr`.

I have:

> ```
> df1
> ```

```
id  something
1   a
2   e
3   i
```

and

> ```
> df2
> ```

```
id  something_else
1   "cow"
4   "how"
3   "wow"
```

Then, I want to assign the correspondent `something_else` with each `something`, so I use.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1,df2, by="id")
```

`by=` will use `"id"` to link both data frames, also `left_join` conserves all the data in `df1`.

Result:

> ```
> left_join(df1,df2, by="id")
> ```

```
id  something  something_else
1   a           "cow"
2   e            NA   # id=2 is not in df2
3   i           "wow"
```